# Child entities IDs are not 0 after ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Couldn't find an adequate answer in my search.

I have a Parent/Child relationship similar to:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="child1_id")
    private Child child1;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="child2_id")
    private Child child2;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="child3_id")
    private Child child3;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Pattern(regexp="FY\\d{4}", message="Format must be 'FYnnnn'")
    private String startYear;

    @Pattern(regexp="FY\\d{4}", message="Format must be 'FYnnnn'")
    private String endYear;
}
```

Here is the service call to save a Parent entity:

```
@Service
class ParentService {
    @Autowired
    private JpaRepository<T,Integer> repo;

    @Transactional
    public T add(T entity) throws Exception {
       ...
       return repo.saveAndFlush(entity)
    }
}
```

When I save a Parent object with incorrect date format in child1, a ConstraintViolationException is properly thrown. After correcting the date format and call the add again, I get a "Detached Entity" error. Walking through debugger what I see is that the id fields of child2 and/or child3 is a non-zero value. The id of the Parent and child1 is properly 0. I am assuming the non-zero ID fields is the cause of the "Detached Entity" error.

My question is why would the IDs be non-zero after the Rollback? I can confirm there is nothing saved to the Child table in the DB.

Versions:
Spring 4.1.0
Hibernate Entity Manager 4.3.6
Hibernate Validator 5.1.2
Hibernate JPA API 1.0.0
Spring Data Commons 1.9.0
Spring Data JPA 1.7.0

---

UPDATE:

Didn't think I would be the only person to ever encounter this problem. So I have solved the issue by catching the exception and forcing the IDs of the children back to 0. Doesn't seem like this is right. Maybe this is a bug? Just have to figure out if it is a bug in Hibernate or Spring.

Comment: Have you tried to merge the detached entity before flushing it again?

Comment: I am using Spring Data so there is no need to manually do a merge. Plus, the issue is not the Detached Entity. If the IDs in the children are rolled back to 0 then there will no Detached Entity error.